# Use maven-project-info-reports-plugin and maven-site-plugin together: One overwrites the index.html of the other

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

In a project I use the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` to create the respective project information as well as some reports. I configured the `maven-site-plugin` to be executed during the `install` phase, so that the reports are generated for each build. Works fine. So far, so good.

[image: project-info-reports]

Now I want to add some custom documentation via the `maven-site-plugin`, as done for example in maven plugins like (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/index.html). On the bar/menu on the left of that page the stuff under *Overview*, *Examples* and so on is created from `doxia` created pages which are referred to in [site.xml](https://github.com/apache/maven-site-plugin/blob/master/src/site/site.xml).

I did try that and created an example markdown page under `src/site/markdown` and a `site.xml` under `src/site`. The markdown page is successfully translated to html.

[image]

However, during the execution of the `maven-site-plugin` plugin the `index.html` seems to be overwritten. The "old" project information is missing (despite the fact that the html pages are still created) and only my new minimalistic page is shown

[image: problem]

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that? I would like all the stuff in the first image as well as a *Overview* menu with custom content

---

## MWE

### `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    ...
    
    <!-- PROPERTIES -->
    <properties>
        ...
        <maven.plugin.project-info-reports.version>3.4.4</maven.plugin.project-info-reports.version>
        <maven.plugin.site.version>4.0.0-M8</maven.plugin.site.version>
        ...
        <jacoco.version>0.8.10</jacoco.version>
        <maven.plugin.checkstyle.version>3.3.0</maven.plugin.checkstyle.version>
        <maven.plugin.javadoc.version>3.5.0</maven.plugin.javadoc.version>
        <maven.plugin.jxr.version>3.3.0</maven.plugin.jxr.version>
        <maven.plugin.surefire.version>3.1.0</maven.plugin.surefire.version>
        ...
    </properties>
    
    ...
    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                
                <!-- Site info -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.site.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${maven.plugin.site.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>site</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>site</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                
                <!-- Projects info -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.project-info-reports.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                
                <!-- Generate the JavaDoc -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.javadoc.version}</version>
                    ...
                <plugin>
                
                ...
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        
        <!-- PLUGINS -->
        <plugins>
        
            ...
            
            <!-- Site info -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
                
            <!-- Projects info -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            ...
            
            <!-- Code coverage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>
    
    <!-- REPORTING -->
    <reporting>
        
        <plugins>
            <!-- Surefire test report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
                    <reportsDirectories>
                        <reportsDirectories>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectories>
                    </reportsDirectories>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Code Coverage report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- JavaDoc report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/apidocs</outputDirectory>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/apidocs</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <author>${maven.plugin.javadoc.author}</author>
                    <!-- Use MathJax for LaTeX in JavaDoc -->
                    <additionalparam>-header '&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;'</additionalparam>
                    <show>${maven.plugin.javadoc.show}</show>
                    <!-- Disable all missing warnings -->
                    <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
                    <quiet>${maven.plugin.javadoc.quiet}</quiet>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet><!-- by default, id = "default" -->
                        <reports><!-- select non-aggregate reports -->
                            <report>javadoc</report>
                            <!--<report>test-javadoc</report>-->
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                    <reportSet><!-- aggregate reportSet, to define in poms having modules -->
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <inherited>false</inherited><!-- don't run aggregate in child modules -->
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Checkstyle report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.checkstyle.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <cacheFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-cachefile</cacheFile>
                    <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
                    <rulesFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-rules.xml</rulesFile>
                    <!--<checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>-->
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- JXR report -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.plugin.jxr.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>jxr-no-fork</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    
</project>
```

### `site.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SITE/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SITE/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/site-2.0.0.xsd"
         name="Content">     <!-- name attribute defines title of the site -->
    
    <!-- Enable Fluido skin -->
    <skin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M6</version>
    </skin>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Add links to pages to menu -->
        <menu name="Overview">
            <item name="Another Page" href="sample.html" />
        </menu>
    </body>

</project>
```

### `sample.md`

```markdown
# Sample page
```

Comment: To which versions resolve `${maven.plugin.site.version}` and `${maven.plugin.project-info-reports.version}` in your POM?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was missing, sorry. I added the properties to the `pom.xml`

Comment: Also `<version>${....version}` is missing at the `jacoco` and `javadoc` plugins with leads to warnings at the build. I added them and I get an `index.html` with my `<artifactId>` and `<description>`: https://imgur.com/BZLySkX.png.

Comment: And you're overriding the `<version>`s of `maven-site-plugin` and `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` plugins which are declared in the `<pluginManagement>` section already. Don't you use an IDE which shows warnings/errors (like the _Problems_ view in Eclipse)?

Comment: The versions are not missing as they are defined during build. I omitted these sections of the POM as they don't have anything to do with the question, really. I was overwriting the <version>, silly me. But again, should not be related to the actual question. Thanks for pointing it out though